# Print the directory where the 'find' linux command finds a match

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a bunch of directories; some of them contain a '.todo' file.

```
/storage/BCC9F9D00663A8043F8D73369E920632/.todo
/storage/BAE9BBF30CCEF5210534E875FC80D37E/.todo
/storage/CBB46FF977EE166815A042F3DEEFB865/.todo
/storage/8ABCBF3194F5D7E97E83C4FD042AB8E7/.todo
/storage/9DB9411F403BD282B097CBF06A9687F5/.todo
/storage/99A9BA69543CD48BA4BD59594169BBAC/.todo
/storage/0B6FB65D4E46CBD8A9B1E704CFACC42E/.todo
```

I'd like the 'find' command to print me only the directory, like this

```
/storage/BCC9F9D00663A8043F8D73369E920632
/storage/BAE9BBF30CCEF5210534E875FC80D37E
/storage/CBB46FF977EE166815A042F3DEEFB865
...
```

here's what I have so far, but it lists the '.todo' file as well

```
#!/bin/bash
STORAGEFOLDER='/storage'
find $STORAGEFOLDER -name .todo  -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Should be dumb stupid, but i'm giving up :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To print the directory name only, use `-printf '%h\n'`. Also recommended to quote your variable with doublequotes.

```
find "$STORAGEFOLDER" -name .todo -printf '%h\n'
```

If you want to process the output:

```
find "$STORAGEFOLDER" -name .todo -printf '%h\n' | xargs ls -l
```

Or use a loop with process substitution to make use of a variable:

```
while read -r DIR; do
    ls -l "$DIR"
done < <(exec find "$STORAGEFOLDER" -name .todo -printf '%h\n')
```

The loop would actually process one directory at a time whereas in xargs the directories are passed `ls -l` in one shot.

To make it sure that you only process one directory at a time, add uniq:

```
find "$STORAGEFOLDER" -name .todo -printf '%h\n' | uniq | xargs ls -l
```

Or

```
while read -r DIR; do
    ls -l "$DIR"
done < <(exec find "$STORAGEFOLDER" -name .todo -printf '%h\n' | uniq)
```

If you don't have bash and that you don't mind about preserving changes to variables outside the loop you can just use a pipe:

```
find "$STORAGEFOLDER" -name .todo -printf '%h\n' | uniq | while read -r DIR; do
    ls -l "$DIR"
done
```

Comment: @Disco Please see my update which gives an example to running `ls`.

Answer (score 2):

The quick and easy answer for stripping off a file name and showing only the directory it’s in is `dirname`:

```
#!/bin/bash
STORAGEFOLDER='/storage'
find "$STORAGEFOLDER" -name .todo  -exec dirname {} \;
```

Comment: the find installed on my mac doesn't have -printf, so this seems like the best option